# Accessing Private Variables

Tags: java, private, actionevent

I have created a class that extends EventButton, which I call BirdButton. However, each of the BirdButtons are instantiated in a separate class. They are instantiated as private variables, but I would like to know which of my BirdButtons were pressed. The separate class, Driver, looks like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class Driver {
    private JFrame win;
    private Animals animals = new Animals();
    private BirdButton nextBtn, enlargeBtn, shrinkBtn, moveToBtn;
    private JTextField field;

    public Driver() {
        win = new JFrame("Angry Animal Name Game");
        win.setBounds(100, 100, 600, 600);
        win.setLayout(null);
        win.setVisible(true);
        nextBtn = new BirdButton( "NEXT", 10, 10, animals);
        win.add(nextBtn, 0);
        enlargeBtn = new BirdButton( "ENLARGE", 10, 60, animals);
        win.add(enlargeBtn, 0);
        shrinkBtn = new BirdButton( "SHRINK", 10, 110, animals);
        win.add(shrinkBtn, 0);
        field = new JTextField();
        field.setBounds(10, 250, 100, 20);
        win.add(field, 0);
        moveToBtn = new BirdButton( "MOVETO", 10, 275, animals, field);
        win.add(moveToBtn, 0);
        win.add(animals, 0);
        animals.recenter();
        win.repaint();
    }
}
```

You can see it creates 4 buttons. I need to know which of these creates my eventAction for my next class which is the button itself:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
public class BirdButton extends EventButton {
    String a;
    public BirdButton(String n, int x, int y, Animals a, JTextField field){
         super(n);
         setLabel(n);
         setBounds(x,y,100,30);
         a = a;
    }

    public BirdButton(String n, int x, int y, Animals a) {
         this(n, x, y, a, null);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         if (e.getSource() == Driver.nextBtn){
             animals.goToNext();
         }
    }
}
```

How could I get my BirdButton class to figure out which of the buttons is pressed, without changing the Driver class?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the observer pattern. In this case the BirdButton can be an Observer and an Observable.  The following links would help.

You may use the following existing JDK objects to implement the observer pattern for your requirements.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html

The following link gives an overview of the implementation approach.

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Design-Pattern/AsimpledemoofObservableandObserver.htm